# If you carry a sack with another creature, and turn invisible, what happens?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, invisibility

Assume a character is strong enough to carry another, small character. Say a Strength 20 character, who can carry 300 pounds when not using variant encumberance, carries a halfling weighing 50 pounds in a large sack, that can hold the halflings' size and weight.

Invisibility states:

> A creature (...) becomes invisible until the spell ends. Anything the target is wearing or carrying is invisible as long as it is on the target's person.

What happens when *invisibility* is cast on the carrying character? They and the sack will turn invisible. Will the creature in the invisible sack be visible, or also invisible (which normally would require a higher level cast)?

(Situation came up in our game tonight).

Comment: I've closed this as a duplicate, it has been asked before (minus the sack, which doesn't seem material to the question).

Comment: Have you ever tried sneaking around invisibly with a halfling in a sack? I mean, I hope not, but it can't be something you can do stealthily :)

Comment: Especially not if you are a Shield guardian :-)